# Use of IsNothing with in Switch function in SSRS expressions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to handle NULL values with in switch function in ssrs. Below is my expression.

```
=Switch( Lookup(Fields!MetricId.Value, Fields!MetricId.Value,Fields!CurrentMonth.Value, "KPIMetricdara")  > 0, 1
```

Here in the above expression The lookup function returns 0 if it finds NULL. Hence i am not able to handle NULL. Can any one help on how do i handle NULL with in switch. I am not in a situation to use other functions other than switch.

Comment: Is your `switch` statement complete? Can you share the data from `KPIMetricdata`? In your `lookup` source and destination is same. Why?

Comment: Can you handle nulls prior to doing the lookup?